# automate app launch at midnight ?

Tags: itunes, macos, applescript, automator

How might I use Automator or Applescript to launch iTunes at midnight, and kill it at 5am ?

(This is the only time when I have unlimited bandwidth..  rural sat-based ISP.. ugg.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is the easiest, non-technical, method:

<sub>(I'm on Snow Leopard, I've edited these to match Mavericks - the exact buttons to click may be wrong)</sub>

1. Make an Applescript and type this: `tell application "iTunes" to activate`
2. Open Calendar.app
3. Make a new event *today* for *00:00*
4. Set it to *repeat every day*
5. *Alert* should be *Open file*. Select *Other* > find the applescript you just made
6. Make an Applescript and type this: `tell application "iTunes" to quit`. Save it somewhere
7. Make another event *tomorrow* for *05:00*
8. Set it to *repeat every day*
9. *Alert* should be *Open file*. Select *Other* > find the applescript you just made

Done!

The calendar app does not have to be running to allow the events to take place.

Answer (score 3):

You can also run `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and add lines like this:

```
0 0 * * * open -a itunes
0 5 * * * osascript -e 'quit app "itunes"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an application like Power Manager to automate the [launching of iTunes](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2010-07-28-how-to-schedule-an-application-to-launch-on-mac-os-x/index.html) and subsequent quitting at 5am.

### Launching iTunes

Launching an application can be achieved with the built-in **Launch an application daily** task:

[image: Power Manager's Schedule Assistant]

### Quitting iTunes

For quitting iTunes at 5:00, I would use the **[Run a script daily](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-05-22-how-to-run-a-shell-script-every-day-on-a-mac/)** task to perform the following AppleScript snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "iTunes" to quit
```

Disclosure: I work on Power Manager for DssW.